# Thymeleaf ocultar botão

Tags: modal, thymeleaf

Tenho um único `modal` que chamo em duas páginas.
quero que o botão `ALTERAR CLIENTE` apareça no modal da página "A" e na página "B" este botão desapareça.
Como disse é o mesmo `modal` para duas páginas diferentes e gostaria de ocultar o botão apenas em uma das páginas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde, você pode colocar uma flag booleana no controller que leva os usuários para estas páginas e usar o `th:if` para mostrar ou não o botão. Por exemplo:

```
<button th:if="${podeAlterarCliente} type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Alterar Cliente</button>
```

Espero ter ajudado!